# beautifulsoup find_all not finding all

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

The following page is an example page of what I am trying to collect information from. https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201610130TBL.html It is a little hard to tell but there are actually 8 tables since it is calling the Scoring summary and Penalty summary by the same class name as the other tables.

and I'm trying to access the tables using the following code, modified slightly to try to troubleshoot the problem.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # imports BeautifulSoup

file = open("Detroit_vs_Tampa.txt")
data = file.read()
file.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
get_table = soup.find_all(class_="overthrow table_container")

print(len(get_table))
```

and my output from this code is 6, which is obviously not right. I further learned that the tables it is leaving out are the two tables underneath the advanced stats report header.

I would like to also point out that since I thought this might be a problem with the parser, I tried using both html.parser and html.parser/lxml directly from the website (as opposed to the text file I'm using in the example code) So I don't think it is a corrupt html.

I had a friend take a quick look at it, thinking it might have been a small oversight by myself, and he was able to notice that the site is using an old IE hack and prepending the table with a comment tag

I'm not 100% sure that is why this is not working, but I've googled this problem and found absolutely nothing. I was hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you tried changing your parser from `lxml` to `html5lib`?

Comment: I have not. I can give that a go in a little bit.

Comment: Edit, I just tried it with html5lib and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last tables are loaded by js, but as you've noticed they are also ambeded in the static html, inside a comment tag.  You can get them with `bs4` if you search for `Comment` objects.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201610130TBL.html'
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
get_table = soup.find_all(class_="overthrow table_container")
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment) and 'table_container' in text)
get_table += BeautifulSoup(comment.string,'lxml').find_all(class_="overthrow table_container")
print(len(get_table))
```

Alternatively you could use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) but it's much heavier than `urllib` or `requests`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201610130TBL.html'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
data = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
get_table = soup.find_all(class_="overthrow table_container")
print(len(get_table))
```

Comment: Yea, Selenium is a sort of last resort option. specifically, because I want to do all of this from text documents to reduce the load on the website. I wasn't aware of the comment. THis is a great fix for this specific problem, I'll have to read up on it for future use.

Comment: Why is selenium harder? Also why does BeautifulSoup not work on JavaScript? (I have a webpage https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201 that I can't scrape links from with beautiful soup, however using Selenium was able to).

Comment: @Katya Selenium is a browser emulator and so it consumes a lot more system resources than requests/urllib that are just HTTP clients. And because it's an emulator, it runs Js code and renders HTML elements produced by it, while simple HTTP clients don't. The problem is not that BeautifulSoup doesn't parse the page correctly (notice that I'm using BeautifulSoup in my Selenium code above), the problem is that requests doesn't return the required HTML elements